# On HTML Canvas, certain overlapping colors are creating unwanted shadows

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors

I am playing with various colors on canvas and just noticed that certain overlapping colors (e.g. red on blue) create shadows, as shown in the image below:

[image]

If you notice, there's about 0.5px wide shadow on the right side of the red circle.

I have the following code:

```
<canvas width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// BG
ctx.fillStyle = '#1c4c72'; ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

// Circle red
ctx.beginPath(); ctx.arc(500, 500, 250, 0, 2 * Math.PI); ctx.fillStyle = '#9a1500'; ctx.fill();

// Circle white
ctx.beginPath(); ctx.arc(500, 500, 150, 0, 2 * Math.PI); ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'; ctx.fill();
```

Is there a remedy for this or is this something to learn to live with? Thanks for any ideas.

Tested on Firefox and Chrome on Windows, latest versions.

Comment: That's probably an optical effect. Do you see it consistently even when zooming in on the image? There will be some antialiasing for the circle and thus there may be some color aberration, but that should be unified around the circle.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, it persists during zoom in/out. Testing with Firefox and Chrome on Windows. If you create a sample canvas using my code above, do you not see the shadow?